# Calling Python functions from MATLAB using matpy

Tags: python, matlab, interface, mex

I have just set up my system for matpy (http://algoholic.eu/matpy/), but it still does not seem to work...

Setup:
- Windows 7 64bit
- MATLAB R2014a 64bit
- WinPython 2.7.9.2 64bit

in MATLAB I entered:

```
>> mex py.cpp '-IC:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.2\python-2.7.9.amd64\include' '-LC:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.2\python-2.7.9.amd64\libs'
Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional'.
MEX completed successfully.
```

Now, if I type

```
>> py_shell
py> print "Hello, World!"
py>
```

nothing happens. How can I check whether my system is operational? What could be the reason it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Winpython must be in your PATH variable to work well.
maybe should you:

- call C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.2\python-2.7.9.amd64\scripts\env.bat before calling Matlab ?
- modify your default system to include it.

Hope it helps or will give you clues

The guy said that it was working with python(x,y), also
http://algoholic.eu/matpy/

==> Are you sure it works on 64 bit ?